# Blender Rigify strange issue with weighting

Tags: rigging, bones, add-on

I have a weird issue with Blender and Rigify.

I've followed this guide to create bones using Rigify and then apply automatic weighting http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-animation-walk-cycle-in-blender-using-rigify--cg-17812

It all seems to go great until I apply the automatic weighting and then I get the strangest result as the mesh seems to mostly disappear. I can replicate this each time I perform the whole process.

Any ideas or feedback? I'm stumped.

[image: The mesh with bones / rigify human biped]

[image: Automatic weighting]

[image: Glitch?]

Comment: Would be easier if you share your blend file for someone to look at. One option is to upload it to [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) and add the link here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Up in the top right you will see that it says Auto-run disabled. You have to press the button beside it that says reload trusted, and it should resolve your issue.